# Can't receive a correct response when posting to same page with AJAX

Tags: javascript, php, ajax

I'm trying to post to same page and retrieve results with AJAX:

**Ajax call:**

```
$(document).ready(function() {
        $("#createaccount").click(function(){
            console.log("Clicked");
            console.log(document.getElementById("textbox").value);
            $.ajax({
                type: "POST",
                data: {'textAreaInput': document.getElementById("textbox").value},
                success: function (data) {
                    if(data.status == "1") {
                        alert("we having a working script");
                    } else {
                        alert("Oops, script is a no go");
                    }

                }
            });
        }); 
    });
```

**Form:**

```
<form method="post" action='' class='form-horizontal' enctype='multipart/form-data' id='startform'>
    <textarea id="textbox"></textarea>
    <button class="btn btn-primary col-lg-12 col-xs-12 col-md-12" name="createaccount" id="createaccount" type="button">Create account</button>
</form>
```

**PHP handler:**

```
<?php
    if (isset($_POST['textAreaInput'])){
        $result = array("status" => "1");
        echo json_encode($result);
        exit;
    }
?>
```

I always receive a `Oops, script is a no go` as an alert, so it seems that something is wrong, but i'm not fully sure at which part. Am i handling it wrong or posting it in the wrong way?

Comment: what is the result on network tab?

Comment: ^^ and `console.log(data)` too so we can see what's inside data currently (though possibly null)

Comment: Shows that 'Form Data' is posted `textAreaInput: {
 "username": 680998442  
}`, response is 200.

Comment: Hmm, it's returning `{"status":"1"}`.

Comment: @Banana Is `data` a string or JSON?

Comment: Console.log outputs `data` as `{"status":"1"}`. Doing `typeof` returns an `object`.

Comment: If it were an object, your `if` would match. You probably only need to set `dataType: "json"` in your ajax options so that it will get parsed automatically.

Comment: Discarding previous - it's returning string, so that's the problem i'm having here. `JSON.parse` throws an exception `Unexpected token < in JSON at position 0`, but i'm going to have to work around that.

Comment: you need to add `datatype : "json"`, encode:true` on your ajax setup

Comment: It seems that server content response is in HTML and `success` does not even compute.

`Connection: Upgrade, Keep-Alive
Content-Type: text/html; charset=UTF-8
Date: Fri, 23 Nov 2018 13:09:04 GMT
Keep-Alive: timeout=5, max=100
Server: Apache/2.4.25 (FreeBSD) OpenSSL/1.0.2k mod_fcgid/2.3.9
Transfer-Encoding: chunked
Upgrade: h2,h2c
X-Powered-By: PHP/5.6.30`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is test.php:

```
<?php
    if (isset($_POST['textAreaInput'])){
        $result = array("status" => "1");
        echo json_encode($result);
        exit;
    }
?>
<form method="post" action='' class='form-horizontal' enctype='multipart/form-data' id='startform'>
    <textarea id="textbox"></textarea>
    <button class="btn btn-primary col-lg-12 col-xs-12 col-md-12" name="createaccount" id="createaccount" type="button">Create account</button>
</form>
<script
  src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.3.1.min.js"
  integrity="sha256-FgpCb/KJQlLNfOu91ta32o/NMZxltwRo8QtmkMRdAu8="
  crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function() {
        $("#createaccount").click(function(){
            console.log("Clicked");
            console.log(document.getElementById("textbox").value);
            $.ajax({
                type: "POST",
                data: {'textAreaInput': document.getElementById("textbox").value},
                dataType: 'json',
                success: function (data) {

                    if(data.status == "1") {
                        alert("we having a working script");
                    } else {
                        alert("Oops, script is a no go");
                    }

                }
            });
        }); 
    });
</script>
```

Comment: For one reason or another, success is not executed any longer (even with `console.log(data)` gives no results).

Comment: Then you are missing something, I have just copy pasted your script , its working fine for me. Recheck you script again.

Comment: That's just strange, i've copied it as well and it's not working. Do you have anything different in PHP?

Comment: I have copy pasted here also , please check my updated answer.

Comment: Really strange, i don't have any JS errors, it just seems that `success` does not execute.

Comment: Try another browser, or try alert something and see if its working.

Comment: I think server is sending it back in html:

`Connection: Upgrade, Keep-Alive
Content-Type: text/html; charset=UTF-8
Date: Fri, 23 Nov 2018 13:09:04 GMT
Keep-Alive: timeout=5, max=100
Server: Apache/2.4.25 (FreeBSD) OpenSSL/1.0.2k mod_fcgid/2.3.9
Transfer-Encoding: chunked
Upgrade: h2,h2c
X-Powered-By: PHP/5.6.30`